# Multiple INSERT statements on one SqlDataSource

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, webforms

For a 'new record' site I have a `FormView` attached to an `SqlDataSource`. The user inputs the data and the `InsertCommand` has the SQL INSERT statement. The thing is that I want to do other queries as part of the initialization, and these queries involve other tables.

Basically I want to execute all these queries when the user clicks the "Insert" button.
The first INSERT gets the values from the input form, but the other three are always the same.

```
INSERT INTO proceso (nombreProceso, macroProceso, analista_id)
VALUES (@nombreProceso,@macroProceso,@analista_id)
INSERT INTO marcador_progreso (marcador_id,state,proceso_id) VALUES (1,'False',@id)
INSERT INTO marcador_progreso (marcador_id,state,proceso_id) VALUES (2,'False',@id) 
INSERT INTO marcador_progreso (marcador_id,state,proceso_id) VALUES (3,'False',@id)
```

When I run this, the first statement apparently gets executed (i.e a new `proceso` record gets inserted) but the other 3 INSERTs do not. How should I proceed to solve this?

The SqlDataDource contains the id parameter

```
 <InsertParameters>
     ... a few parameters...
     <asp:Parameter Name="id" />
</InsertParameters>
```

Comment: @id is returned by the first insert?

Comment: It is a parameter in the <InsertParameters> fields. Just edited my question to show it.

Comment: what error gives you? Tell us more. Or says that everything just appeared to be fine, and the values are not inserted?

Comment: No errors. Apparently it executes, and as I said the first INSERT does execute correctly, but I'm not sure what's happening to the other 3 statements. Is it legal to put multiple INSERTs into one InsertCommand field?

Comment: as I read from here http://forums.asp.net/t/1167387.aspx/1 it looks like its possible to do more than 1 insert.. But check if its correct your insertStatement

Comment: can you wrap your inserts into a storeprocedure?

Comment: I guess its not my original question but can you show how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please correct me if I'm wrong but it seems to me you want the `@id` thing to be the ID of the row just inserted into `proceso`. At least that seems to follow from the corresponding `marcador_progreso` column's name (`proceso_id`). If my surmise is correct then you don't need a *parameter* called `id`. The `@id` in your query should be a *local variable* initialised by the ID of the row inserted by the first `INSERT`.

If `proceso`'s ID is an integer `IDENTITY` column, then change your script like this:

```
INSERT INTO proceso (nombreProceso, macroProceso, analista_id)
VALUES (@nombreProceso,@macroProceso,@analista_id);

DECLARE @id int;
SET @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

INSERT INTO marcador_progreso (marcador_id,state,proceso_id) VALUES (1,'False',@id);
INSERT INTO marcador_progreso (marcador_id,state,proceso_id) VALUES (2,'False',@id);
INSERT INTO marcador_progreso (marcador_id,state,proceso_id) VALUES (3,'False',@id);
```

And remove the `id` parameter.

The [`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) function returns the last value inserted into an `IDENTITY` column of any table in the current scope of execution.